# Different behavior of image rendering mode in UIKit and SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have this code in SwiftUI:

```
        let image = UIImage(named: "white.png")!
          .withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        Image(uiImage: image)
          .tint(.yellow)
```

Note that `white.png` is an image in white color.

The result image is white color (not red nor yellow). I think this makes sense because I used "alwaysOriginal", which renders images in its intrinsic color.

However, when I tried this in UIKit:

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "white.png")!
      .withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.tintColor = .yellow
    view.addSubview(imageView)
```

The result is a red image. This is strange because alwaysOriginal should have make it non-colorable. Why are the behaviors different across UIKit and SwiftUI? Or did I understand `alwaysOriginal` incorrectly?

Image below (white color, so you can't see it)

[image]

Comment: pleaes add a screenshot of your result or attach the image to try with the code.

Comment: @B25Dec added the image at the end

Comment: The use of `alwaysOriginal` means the image view tint will have no effect. But the `withTintColor` will have an effect. The rendering mode is set on the resulting image of `withTintColor`. The only confusing thing here is why the image isn't red in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the behaviour would be different in both Swift and SwiftUI. Because In UIKit, the withTintColor method is used to directly change the tint color of an image. When you call withTintColor on a UIImage instance, it applies the specified color directly to the image.

However, in SwiftUI, the Image view does not have a direct equivalent of withTintColor. Instead, SwiftUI uses the colorMultiply modifier to apply a color multiplication effect to the image. And for your understanding i am adding code and screenshot both for your ref.

```swift
{
        VStack(spacing: 30){
        let image = UIImage(named: "123.png")!
        Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .colorMultiply(.red)
            
            UIKitImage()
        }
        .background(Color.black)

    }
```

Swift's ImageView

```swift
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        let image = UIImage(named: "123.png")!
              .withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            imageView.tintColor = .yellow
            view.addSubview(imageView)
           
        return view
```

Also i would suggest you to read more details about how an Image could be different if its a vector image or a template image. Vector images mostly of the time can adopt various size and color very efficiently while template images have some restrictions.
See the example below: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/providing_images_for_different_appearances

The result attaching a screenshot. Tried on Xcode 14.3. I hope it helps.

[image]